# Centos set time without ntp

Tags: centos, time

I've a centos 6.5 server. The time is 20mins ahead so I want to fix it. I can't use ntp as I've read it requires an input port to be opened in the firewall but I don't have control on the external firewall.

I've seen that there're two time: system and hardware.

My priority is to have the time displayed correclty on wordpress. Is it sufficient to set the system time and can I leave the HW time wrong? Which effects can it have?

This is the command to set system time, right?

> date MMDDhhmmYYYY

Is there anything I've to check on the server or I can set the system time safely?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not answer your question, because I think you may see more problems with **ntpd** than there really are:

> I can't use ntp as I've read it requires an input port to be opened in the firewall but I don't have control on the external firewall.

You seem to believe that you need to do something to your firewall, for *ntpd* to work correctly. This is not true: *ntpd* will open UDP port 123 no matter what you do, even if you used *iptables* to block it explicitly, provided you allow established traffic as usual. The reason is obvious: *ntpd* **begins** the communication with the servers, their replies are then seen as *ESTABLISHED* connections, which every self-respecting firewall will allow.

Thus there is no reason to fear, you may just install *ntpd* on your system/account. If you need any further info on how better secure your pc, the ever-helpful Arch wiki has [this eloquent answer by ataraxia](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=959068#p959068).

EDIT:

Under the hypothesis that the firewall behind which you find yourself is really blocking all outgoing ports except for TCP port 80 (this sounds more like a blockade than a firewall, but never mind that), there is another solution, **tlsdate**, which uses TCP port 443 (not usually blocked, if TCP port 80 is allowed). Its man page says:

> tlsdate is a tool for setting the system clock by hand or by communication with the network. It does  not  set  the  Real
>          Time Clock. It is designed to be as secure as TLS (RFC 2246) but of course the security of TLS is often reduced to which‐
>          ever CA racket you believe is trustworthy. By default, tlsdate trusts your local CA root store - so any of  these  compa‐
>          nies could assist in a MITM attack against you and you'd be screwed.
>
> This  tool is designed to be run by hand or as a system daemon. It must be run as root or otherwise have the proper caps;
>          it will not be able to set the system time without running as root or another privileged user.

Comment: All ports but http (80) are blocked explicitly by an external firewall. Do you confirm that it's ok?

Comment: @testermaster Outgoing or incoming?

Comment: first of all thanks for your help. How can I test if UDP port 123 is "opened", before installing ntp?

Comment: @testermaster You cannot: you may only try it. You see, it gets opened (unless your firewall is a total blckade) by the signals which your own copy  of ntp  is sending out. Besides, disinstalling is very easy...

Comment: ntp executed correctly! Is it normal that HW time is still wrong? I've opened a new question here: http://superuser.com/questions/923060/ntp-system-time-different-from-hardware-time thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

From the date man page:

```
   -s, --set=STRING
          set time described by STRING
```

You can use `date -s 11:00` for example to update the time to 11:00.